# Java library or code to properly parse comma-separated list of key=value assignments

Tags: java

This feels like something that must have re-invented many many times and for which there should be not one but several libraries.

I would like to parse lines of text that contain several "assignments" of the form "key=value", separated by commas. The catch is that it should be possible to specify the value as closely to how Java allows to specify strings or numeric values as possible. For example escaping Strings, specifying Unicode characters, or specifying tab characters as \t.

Does anyone know of an open-source or LGPL library that has methods to do this?

UPDATE: I do not think see (yet) how properties can be easily used for this as I have to process a String that contains several key=value pairs, separated by commas. The problem here is that unless the parser knows how to properly parse the values (which can of course contain commas), there is no easy way to split the String up at the commas. Essentially what I want to do is convert a string like this: `var1=1, var2="asdf",var3="x,y,z\n",var4="\""` into a hashmap  or  where Value wraps something that is either a String, a boolan, or a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Java Properties API can be used for this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: No, because I have a String that contains a comma-separated list of such assignments and because Properties also support quite a different syntax. I would like the syntax to be more closely to what variable assignment of String constant looks in Java or Groovy, without all the overhead of creating a lexer, parser etc.

Answer (score 1):

No need for Library.

```
    String[] strArray= "var1=1,var2=2,var3=test".split(",");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String pair : strArray) {
        String split[] = pair.split("=");
        map.put(split[0], split[1]);
    }
```

If you really want to use Library you can try [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
Iterable<String> split = Splitter.on(',').omitEmptyStrings().split("var1=1,var2=2,var3=test");
```

Comment: Uhm, no, the reason why one would want a library is because obviously, both equal signs and commas can be contained in the value, e.g. var="==,\"" would be a valid assignment.

Comment: Library would help you to ease the process but you should do this with your own algorithm. (RegEx would help in this situation)

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about property files? You can do something like this using [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.properties"));
```

Comment: No, because I have a String that contains a comma-separated list of such assignments and because Properties also support quite a different syntax. 
I would like the syntax to be more closely to what variable assignment of String constant looks in Java or Groovy, without all the overhead of creating a lexer, parser etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use java java.util.Properties ?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("myfile.properties"));
```

Comment: I need to parse a comma separated list of "assignments". With properties, parsin the comma-separated list cannot be done and Properties, apart from being strictly line-oriented, also support quite a range of different additional syntax (whitespace or colon instead of assignment character, comments etc)